# Why is softwareupdated taking up all my memory?

Tags: macos, memory, software-update

The process softwareupdated seems to be taking up way too much memory. It can take up to 400 MB RAM sometimes. I can't nail down what is causing this to happen, so I've been watching my console closely. I've narrowed one incident to a 15 minute period, but I still can't see what might be causing this. I am attaching the console output below. Usually softwareupdated only takes up 18 MB. When it gets up to 400 MB, it won't ever go back down unless I restart my computer. Its like it can't release the memory or something. Its very frustrating since it slows my computer down considerably. I have also had my computer freeze a few times requiring a manual shutdown. It seems the problems started with update 10.10.2, but this may be a coincidence.

edit: Here are some updated screenshots when the process is acting up.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Has anyone else experienced this? What can I do to fix this?

```
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5  MAC AUTH succeeded
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #1, bssid b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 11
3/5/15 4:23:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5  MAC AUTH succeeded
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to b8:8d:12:61:0a:e5
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 11
3/5/15 4:23:21.000 PM kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
3/5/15 4:23:22.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
3/5/15 4:24:36.256 PM storeaccountd[259]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fe1e0d067c0> connection from pid 1955 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7fe1e0d07cb0> (PID 1955)
3/5/15 4:24:36.591 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:24:38.838 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:24:39.043 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[1962]: objc[1962]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
3/5/15 4:24:39.052 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:24:41.739 PM WindowServer[136]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Safari" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
3/5/15 4:24:41.817 PM WindowServer[136]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Safari" after 1.08 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
3/5/15 4:24:42.743 PM locationd[198]: Couldn't find a requirement string for masquerading client /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Parsec.framework
3/5/15 4:24:42.744 PM locationd[198]: could not get apple languages array, assuming english
3/5/15 4:24:43.512 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:04.472 PM nsurlstoraged[216]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=COMMIT;, error-code=1, error-message=cannot commit - no transaction is active
3/5/15 4:25:14.615 PM nsurlstoraged[216]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=COMMIT;, error-code=1, error-message=cannot commit - no transaction is active
3/5/15 4:25:34.289 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:34.410 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:35.146 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[53]: Session 100051 created
3/5/15 4:25:35.661 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:37.920 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:38.469 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:39.089 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:39.781 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:39.984 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:42.012 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:42.789 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:51.992 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.98330179-55A8-4EFA-A3E1-D8B74979F201[1980]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
3/5/15 4:25:52.266 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:53.828 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:25:56.756 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:00.187 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:01.862 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1990]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:26:01.863 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1990]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:26:01.948 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:02.098 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:03.066 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:03.495 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:26:07.053 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1993]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:26:07.053 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1993]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:26:24.810 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.Networking.22DFCA4E-C337-4C8F-8EB6-B5FE2E9132BA[1967]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
3/5/15 4:26:36.037 PM nsurlstoraged[216]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=COMMIT;, error-code=1, error-message=cannot commit - no transaction is active
3/5/15 4:26:40.100 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:26:43.984 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:26:47.054 PM nsurlstoraged[216]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=COMMIT;, error-code=1, error-message=cannot commit - no transaction is active
3/5/15 4:27:37.459 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:27:37.877 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:27:38.525 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:28:07.704 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:28:08.557 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:28:27.237 PM com.apple.backupd[1931]: Copied 219 items (68.3 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5306.
3/5/15 4:29:00.438 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:29:01.170 PM networkd[145]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.1972 setting source application without entitlement
3/5/15 4:29:02.257 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[2005]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:29:02.257 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[2005]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:29:04.387 PM com.apple.backupd[1931]: Created new backup: 2015-03-05-162902
3/5/15 4:29:07.662 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.2 instead of 10.10.2. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
3/5/15 4:29:07.906 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x9976d7c7 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135
3/5/15 4:29:07.906 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x91171130 _dispatch_client_callout + 50
3/5/15 4:29:07.907 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x911710b5 dispatch_once_f + 251
3/5/15 4:29:07.907 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x911720d8 dispatch_once + 31
3/5/15 4:29:07.907 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x996ffe88 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1050
3/5/15 4:29:07.907 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 5   CarbonCore                          0x996ffa39 Gestalt + 150
3/5/15 4:29:07.907 PM com.apple.qtkitserver[1975]: 6   QuickTime                           0x9b5462ba QTSAddUserAgentExtraTags + 221
3/5/15 4:29:09.769 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:29:12.000 PM kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
3/5/15 4:29:12.803 PM fseventsd[20]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
3/5/15 4:29:13.052 PM mds[32]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fc28304a000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
3/5/15 4:29:13.000 PM kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3
3/5/15 4:29:14.462 PM com.apple.backupd[1931]: Backup completed successfully.
3/5/15 4:29:15.424 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6  MAC AUTH succeeded
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 149,+1
3/5/15 4:29:17.000 PM kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
3/5/15 4:29:22.000 PM kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Time Machine Backups on device disk3s2
3/5/15 4:29:23.221 PM com.apple.backupd[1931]: Ejected Time Machine disk image: /Volumes/Data/Jason’s MacBook Pro.sparsebundle
3/5/15 4:29:23.000 PM kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_unmount: /Volumes/Data, flags 0, pid 2021
3/5/15 4:29:23.000 PM kernel[0]: ASP_TCP Disconnect: triggering reconnect by bumping reconnTrigger from curr value 0 on so 0xffffff8020b397b0
3/5/15 4:29:24.000 PM kernel[0]: ASP_TCP Detach: Reply queue not empty?
3/5/15 4:29:24.162 PM com.apple.backupd[1931]: Ejected Time Machine network volume.
3/5/15 4:30:27.552 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[2025]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:30:27.553 PM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[2025]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
3/5/15 4:31:15.528 PM SystemUIServer[224]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
3/5/15 4:31:32.083 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:33:32.783 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:33:32.783 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:33:34.153 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:33:34.153 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:33:35.336 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:33:35.336 PM Mail[205]: No worthy mechs found
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6  MAC AUTH succeeded
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #2, bssid b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to b8:8d:12:61:0a:e6
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 149,+1
3/5/15 4:34:18.000 PM kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
3/5/15 4:34:21.421 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:34:21.475 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[53]: Session 100053 created
3/5/15 4:34:21.960 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[53]: Killing auth hosts
3/5/15 4:34:21.961 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[53]: Session 100049 destroyed
3/5/15 4:34:21.962 PM logind[67]: -[SessionManager getClient:withRole:inAuditSession:]:241: ERROR: No session dictionary for audit session 100053
3/5/15 4:34:21.962 PM logind[67]: _SMGetSessionAgent:73: ERROR: __SMGetClientForAuditSessionAgent failed 2
3/5/15 4:34:21.963 PM IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent[2033]: SACShieldWindowShowing:925: ERROR: NULL response
3/5/15 4:34:24.339 PM identityservicesd[256]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7fa369c5aef0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7fa369f3e430> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
3/5/15 4:34:24.340 PM identityservicesd[256]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7fa369c5aef0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7fa369d97b90> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
3/5/15 4:34:26.326 PM identityservicesd[256]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7fa369c5aef0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7fa369e46e90> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
3/5/15 4:34:26.326 PM identityservicesd[256]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7fa369c5aef0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7fa369f3bc20> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
3/5/15 4:34:26.327 PM identityservicesd[256]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7fa369c5aef0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7fa369ccc180> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
3/5/15 4:34:35.867 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
3/5/15 4:34:44.339 PM Messages[217]: [Warning] Could not set kMDItemOriginSenderDisplayName on file file:///Users/User/Library/Messages/Attachments/56/06/9FC693B3-E614-4820-A7E0-CDG8F61B2224/08%20What%20Is%20New%20Orleans%20Part%202.m4a
3/5/15 4:34:47.538 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[2038]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
3/5/15 4:34:48.937 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.quicklookd.2038) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/Resources/quicklookd.app
3/5/15 4:34:49.600 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[53]: Session 100054 created
3/5/15 4:40:40.037 PM bird[234]: Assertion failed: ![_xpcClients containsObject:client]
```

Comment: I’m getting this too.

Answer (score 2):

My daemon shows 418 MB of RAM in Activity monitor (and see details below). It's not any concern for any of my Macs.

If you open up your Activity Monitor, you will likely see that the memory pressure (the important number) is green.

[image]

As long as you aren't in yellow, the system will use RAM as it sees fit, so **there's really no problem with the numbers you report**. All your RAM isn't committed, there's no point in the system reducing allocations with no pressure.

Also, consider control clicking on the memory column (when viewing memory) and select all the memory items. You can then update the post with real/private/shared memory footprint as well as the nominal memory size.

You could also double click on the line item for **softwareupdated** to inspect it:

[image]

The real thing to track will be to write down the exact time of each freeze and dig into the logs when that happens. Ram usage by the update daemon is almost certainly not the cause of that instability.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will continue to monitor my system. 400 MB is not of great concern to me, its just the computer starts behaving badly at the same time that softwareupdated acts up. i hope you are right, but I have never noticed this behavior before. I still am usually working in the green, but it is becoming a bigger challenge on my 2011 Macbook Pro with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: My `softwareupdated` is 437MB, although the "compressed mem" column is 404MB which could mean that it's only actually occupying 30MB? Regardless, it does seem excessive, especially since there doesn't seem to be any reason for `softwareupdated` to run in the background at all. It's the second biggest process after `kernel_task` for me.

Comment: Here are two reasons to load it in the background. It launches at boot and then all the memory and code are set so that when you choose to run an update (or a urgent security update is issued), you don't get a failure due to other processes taking the ram. Most people enable periodic checks and this is the worker that does the checks throughout the day and month.

Comment: I have 32gb in my 10.10.5 Yosemite iMac with Memory pressure in the Yellow and softwareupdated is still taking up 550MB. My uptime is 21 days. Time for a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the process in Activity monitor